# Selection with mouse in DataGrid is not possible with filtered collection

Tags: wpf, datagrid, filter

We have a ComboBox with a DataGrid, based on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFCustomComboBox.aspx).
Now we wan't to have the possibility to filter the values. So I implemented [this one](http://dotbay.blogspot.com/2009/04/building-filtered-combobox-for-wpf.html).

Filtering is working fine and it's possible to select suggestions with up and down on the keyboard. But it is not possible to select one with the mouse.

Why is this not possible? How can I fix that?

Here is the code of our combobox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomControls {
[DefaultProperty("Columns")]
[ContentProperty("Columns")]
[TemplatePart(Name = s_partPopupDataGrid, Type = typeof(DataGrid))]
public class GridCombo : ComboBox {
    #region Static

    internal static readonly DependencyProperty ReplaceColumnsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ReplaceColumns",
            typeof(IEnumerable<DataGridBoundColumn>),
            typeof(GridCombo),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CellStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CellStyle",
            typeof(Style),
            typeof(GridCombo),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumSearchLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MinimumSearchLength",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(GridCombo),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(1));

    static GridCombo() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(GridCombo), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(GridCombo)));
    }

    #endregion

    // ======================================================================
    #region Fields & Constructors

    private const string s_partPopupDataGrid = "PART_PopupDataGrid";

    // Columns of DataGrid
    private ObservableCollection<DataGridBoundColumn> _columns;

    private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> _properties = new Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>>();

    // Attached DataGrid control
    private DataGrid _popupDataGrid;
    private Popup _popup;

    private string _oldFilter = string.Empty;
    private string _currentFilter = string.Empty;

    #endregion

    // ======================================================================
    #region Public

    public Style CellStyle {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(CellStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CellStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If set, the "Columns" property is ignored. Useful if you need
    /// a dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    internal IEnumerable<DataGridBoundColumn> ReplaceColumns {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DataGridBoundColumn>)GetValue(ReplaceColumnsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReplaceColumnsProperty, value); }
    }

    // The property is default and Content property for CustComboBox
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ObservableCollection<DataGridBoundColumn> Columns {
        get {
            if (_columns == null) {
                _columns = new ObservableCollection<DataGridBoundColumn>();
            }
            return _columns;
        }
    }

    // Apply theme and attach columns to DataGrid popup control
    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
        if (_popupDataGrid == null) {
            _popupDataGrid = Template.FindName(s_partPopupDataGrid, this) as DataGrid;
            if (_popupDataGrid != null && (_columns != null || ReplaceColumns != null)) {
                if (ReplaceColumns != null) {
                    foreach (var column in ReplaceColumns) {
                        var copy = DataGridFix.CopyDataGridColumn(column);
                        _popupDataGrid.Columns.Add(copy);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Add columns to DataGrid columns
                    for (int i = 0; i < _columns.Count; i++)
                        _popupDataGrid.Columns.Add(_columns[i]);
                }

                // Add event handler for DataGrid popup
                _popupDataGrid.MouseDown += PopupDataGridMouseDown;
                _popupDataGrid.SelectionChanged += PopupDataGridSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
        if (_popup == null) {
            _popup = Template.FindName("PART_Popup", this) as Popup;
            if (_popup != null && _popupDataGrid != null) {
                _popup.Opened += PopupOpened;
                _popup.Focusable = true;
            }
        }

        // Call base class method
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    [Description("Length of the search string that triggers filtering.")]
    [Category("Filtered ComboBox")]
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int MinimumSearchLength {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinimumSearchLengthProperty); }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set { SetValue(MinimumSearchLengthProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    // ======================================================================
    #region Protected

    // When selection changed in combobox (pressing  arrow key down or up) must be synchronized with opened DataGrid popup
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        if (_popupDataGrid == null)
            return;

        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) {
            if (IsDropDownOpen) {
                _popupDataGrid.SelectedItem = SelectedItem;
                ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDropDownOpened(EventArgs e) {
        if (_popupDataGrid == null)
            return;

        _popupDataGrid.SelectedItem = SelectedItem;

        base.OnDropDownOpened(e);
    }

    protected TextBox EditableTextBox {
        get { return Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", this) as TextBox; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (!IsEditable) {
            base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
            return;
        }

        ClearFilter();
        int temp = SelectedIndex;
        SelectedIndex = -1;
        Text = string.Empty;
        SelectedIndex = temp;
        base.OnPreviewLostKeyboardFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (!IsEditable) {
            base.OnKeyUp(e);
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down) {
            // Navigation keys are ignored
        } else if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter) {
            // Explicit Select -> Clear Filter
            ClearFilter();
        } else {
            // The text was changed
            if (Text != _oldFilter) {
                // Clear the filter if the text is empty,
                // apply the filter if the text is long enough
                if (Text.Length == 0 || Text.Length >= MinimumSearchLength) {
                    RefreshFilter();
                    IsDropDownOpen = true;

                    // Unselect
                    EditableTextBox.SelectionStart = int.MaxValue;
                }
            }

            base.OnKeyUp(e);

            _currentFilter = Text;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable oldValue, IEnumerable newValue) {
        if (!IsEditable) {
            base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
            return;
        }

        if (newValue != null) {
            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue);
            view.Filter += FilterPredicate;
        }
        if (oldValue != null) {
            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue);
            view.Filter -= FilterPredicate;
        }
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (!IsEditable) {
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            return;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Tab || e.Key == Key.Enter) {
            // Explicit Selection -> Close ItemsPanel
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        } else if (e.Key == Key.Escape) {
            // Escape -> Close DropDown and redisplay Filter
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
            SelectedIndex = -1;
            Text = _currentFilter;
        } else {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down) {
                // Arrow Down -> Open DropDown
                IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
            base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        }

        _oldFilter = Text;
    }

    #endregion

    // ======================================================================
    #region Private

    private void RefreshFilter() {
        if (ItemsSource != null) {
            var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ItemsSource);
            view.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void ClearFilter() {
        _currentFilter = string.Empty;
        RefreshFilter();
    }

    private bool FilterPredicate(object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (Text.Length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        var properties = GetProperties(value.GetType());
        foreach (var property in properties) {
            var propertyValue = (property.GetValue(value, null) ?? string.Empty).ToString();
            if (propertyValue.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(Text.ToLowerInvariant())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type type) {
        if (!_properties.ContainsKey(type)) {
            _properties.Add(type, new List<PropertyInfo>());

            foreach (var column in _columns) {
                if (column.Binding != null && column.Binding is Binding) {
                    var path = ((Binding)column.Binding).Path.Path;
                    var property = type.GetProperty(path);
                    if (property != null) {
                        _properties[type].Add(property);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return _properties[type];
    }

    private void PopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
    }

    private void ScrollIntoView(object item) {
        if (item != null && _popupDataGrid.Items.Contains(item))
            _popupDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(item);
    }

    // Synchronize selection between Combo and DataGrid popup
    private void PopupDataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        // When open in Blend prevent raising exception
        if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) {
            var grid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (grid != null && grid.IsVisible) {
                SelectedItem = grid.SelectedItem;
            }
        }
    }

    // Event for DataGrid popup MouseDown
    private void PopupDataGridMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        DataGrid dg = sender as DataGrid;
        if (dg != null) {
            var dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree and stop when dep is one of ..
            while ((dep != null) &&
                   !(dep is DataGridCell) &&
                   !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader)) {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            if (dep == null)
                return;

            if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader) {
                // do something
            }

            // When user clicks to DataGrid cell, popup have to be closed
            if (dep is DataGridCell) {
                IsDropDownOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

The following Xaml can be used to test it:

```
<Window x:Class="GridComboTestView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:combo="clr-namespace:CustomControls;assembly=CustomControls"
    Height="300" Width="300">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="ChangeElements" Command="{Binding ChangeElements}" />
    <combo:GridCombo 
        x:Name="GridCombo" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Number"
        IsEditable="True"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
        MaxDropDownHeight="100">
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </combo:GridCombo>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling base() on PopupDataGridMouseDown.  Not sure this will fix it but something to look at.

Comment: PopupDataGridMouseDown is an event handler and not an overridden method, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelS Yes I am aware that it is an event handler. Did you try adding base.OnMouseDown(e); as the last line in that event handler?